# Convert from asset balance to currency balance?

Tags: balances, assets

**Context:** I'm creating a pallet with a simple DEX (decentralised exchange) functionality. I need to perform some arithmetic operations on balances for liquidity pools.

**Problem:** How can I convert from asset balance to currency balance? I am aware of the [BalanceConversion](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/trait.BalanceConversion.html) trait and its [BalanceToAssetBalance](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_assets/struct.BalanceToAssetBalance.html) impelementation, but it only converts the other way (which also need, btw). Could an asset balance -> currency balance conversion be implemented in a similar way *without modifying* the `assets` pallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out I didn't actually need this kind of conversion which `BalanceToAssetBalance` offers. It's based on the ratio between the fungible’s minimum balance and the minimum asset balance, which was not relevant in my use case. So I ended up simply using the [`Convert`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Convert.html) trait (which, btw is required by `BalanceToAssetBalance`). [Here's](https://github.com/Wiezzel/substrate-dex/blob/203dd718020232439c26b4acefd1ceac0cbc99fd/src/lib.rs#L81-L83) how I implemented it.